# ASP.Net MVC 3 session management when using IOC pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, session-state

I am trying to use the IOC pattern and could not find the perfect way of implementing the state management using the same. Would be great if someone can help me with the same. Thank you.

Comment: are you using `Unity` containers

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is first create an Interface containing all the properties you would need to store in the Session (i.e.: the context):

```
using ProjectName.Core.Domain;

namespace ProjectName.Core.Interfaces
{
    public interface IProjectNameSessionContext
    {
        string StringProperty1 { get; set; }
        bool BoolProperty1 { get; set; }
        ProjectName.Core.Domain.Entity1 DomainEntity1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then create a class that implements this interface, mark it as serializable:

```
using ProjectName.Core.Interfaces;

namespace ProjectName.Front.SessionData
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ProjectNameSessionContext : IProjectNameSessionContext
    {
        public string StringProperty1 { get; set; }
        public bool BoolProperty1 { get; set; }
        public ProjectName.Core.Domain.Entity1 DomainEntity1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally tell your IOC to bind the interface with the class at runtime an instantiate an object in HttpSession context.

It looks like this with StrucureMap:

```
For<Core.Interfaces.IProjectNameSessionContext>().LifecycleIs(new HttpSessionLifecycle()).Use<ProjectNameSessionContext>();
```

Hope that helps!